# Array of a struct

Tags: c++

I'm changing my code to work with arrays instead of a linked list.

The fact is I'm receiving this error:

> error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token

And I'm doing this:

```
typedef struct MyStage * stage_t;

struct MyStage {
    ...
}

stage_t[] stages = new stage_t[len];
```

If I declare like this:

```
struct stage_t stages[len];
```

I receive an error like this:

> error: array type has incomplete element type

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you aware that the posted code is c++ and no c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this

```
stage_t[] stages = new stage_t[len];
```

it's invalid, it's not Java, in c++ you need to declare a pointer instead, like this

```
stage_t *stages = new stage_t[len];
```

the other syntax works for array declaration, arrays can be converted to pointers, and they are without any extra code, but when you need a dynamically allocated array you need to use a pointer.

Also, you need to remember to

```
delete[] stages;
```

Comment: No, he must remember to use `std::vector`.

Comment: That is your opinion, but there are legitimate situations where the code above makes sense. If you for example need the data to persist after a function call. Pointers are still useful in the c++ language.

Comment: Are "we" actually down voting answers based on OP's data structure types? That's just stupid.

Comment: @iharob what happens if an exception is thrown after the `new` but before the `delete` ?